# Perl script to check remote server for process

Tags: linux, perl, scripting

I am having a bit of a problem with a script that I setup. A little background:

The function of the script is to read from a list of servers that is in a text file separated by :: , log on to the servers, check to see that mysql is running and report back. The file is configured such that each line has:   Servername::Ip address::port number

The problem I am having is that I think perl is trying to concatenate the ip address that I am feeding to the function I have in the code. Can anyone point my in the right direction?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                           

use strict;
use warnings;

open(FH, '<', 'serverlist_test') or error("Cannot open file , ($!)");
while (my $line = <FH>) {
    our ($name, $ip, $port) = split(/::/, $line);
    my $version = &MySQL_check($ip, $port);                                                                                    
}
close FH;

sub MySQL_check {

    my $issue = `ssh -t root@"$_[0]" -p$"_[1]" 'ps axco command | grep -i mysql'`;
    print $issue;
    if ($issue =~ /mysql/) {                                                                             
      return "Mysql found"; 
    } else {                                                                                             
       return "Mysql not found";                                                                         
    }                                                                                                    
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank You.

Comment: it looks like you are recording the SSH port, not the port that TSQL is running on.

Comment: Hello Frank , this is part of a larger script that I had written in bash and am converting to perl; there are a lot of checks that can only be done via ssh and run on the remote server , I firewall off all the other ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in some print-debugging code so you can see the command being run. So change:

```
my $issue = `ssh -t root@"$_[0]" -p$"_[1]" 'ps axco command | grep -i mysql'`;
```

to

```
my $command = qq`ssh -t root@"$_[0]" -p$"_[1]" 'ps axco command | grep -i mysql'`;
warn "Going to run \"$command\""; # comment this out when your code works!
my $issue = `$command`;
```

This should flag up the problem with the command. It's almost certainly because you didn't `chomp` the lines you read from the file, so the port number actually has `\n` after it.

Comment: Hello Peter, I was not aware of qq, and I will certainly be using this in the future! Thank you for pointing out that I had a new line creeping into my code; that was indeed the case. I have fixed the code and can say that it works now.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $issue = `ssh -t root@"$_[0]" -p$"_[1]" 'ps axco command | grep -i mysql'`;
```

look at

```
-p$"_[1]"
```

which should be

```
-p "$_[1]"
```

Comment: Hello ugexe,  You are correct that typo was mine , I re-added the quotations manually after I had pasted the code in. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1):

Your code with a few modifications

```
...
while (my $line = <FH>) {
    chomp($line); #MOD -- remove newline
    our ($name, $ip, $port) = split("::", $line); #MOD -- change delimiter
...

sub MySQL_check {

    my $issue = `ssh -t root@"$_[0]" -p"$_[1]" 'ps axco command | grep -i mysql'`; #MOD -- fix misplaced double quotes
...
```

Comment: Hello Rohit, I appreciate the effort you took , and yes you are correct; I was not chomping the lines and it was adding a new line at the end. Thank you for the code!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
our ($name, $ip, $port) = split('::', $line);
```

Comment: Hello foampile , does it really make a difference if I use '' "" or // as delimiters? Just asking as I am still kinda new to perl.