# Perl script to log in to server and execute command

Tags: linux, perl

I am new to perl. I want to run a perl script on terminal that takes in the ip address of another server , logs into it (with username and password), executes a bash command and returns the result. Any guidance will be appreciated. For eg. Similar codes, questions, perl functions that may help et cetera.

Comment: 1. Pick a network protocol that will allow you to run bash commands. 2. Make sure the target machine is running a server that implements that protocol. 3. Search [cpan](https://metacpan.org/) for a module that implements that protocol.

Comment: For example, [Perl script to check remote server for process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278738/perl-script-to-check-remote-server-for-process) has a similar command.

Comment: Try something and then ask something specific. This is so vague.

Comment: @Quentin - Thanks. That was a start. Helped me arrive at Net::SSH:Perl

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w  
use strict;  
use Net::SSH qw(ssh);  

my $host = "server1.domain.com";  
my $user = "user1";  
my $remotedir = "/home/user1/";  
my $cmd = "/bin/ls";  
ssh("$user\@$host", $cmd);
```